# "No match Found" when using matcher's group method

Tags: java, regex, http-headers

I'm using `Pattern`/`Matcher` to get the response code in an HTTP response. `groupCount` returns 1, but I get an exception when trying to get it! Any idea why?

Here's the code:

```
//get response code
String firstHeader = reader.readLine();
Pattern responseCodePattern = Pattern.compile("^HTTP/1\\.1 (\\d+) OK$");
System.out.println(firstHeader);
System.out.println(responseCodePattern.matcher(firstHeader).matches());
System.out.println(responseCodePattern.matcher(firstHeader).groupCount());
System.out.println(responseCodePattern.matcher(firstHeader).group(0));
System.out.println(responseCodePattern.matcher(firstHeader).group(1));
responseCode = Integer.parseInt(responseCodePattern.matcher(firstHeader).group(1));
```

And here's the output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
true
1
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Unknown Source)
 at cs236369.proxy.Response.<init>(Response.java:27)
 at cs236369.proxy.ProxyServer.start(ProxyServer.java:71)
 at tests.Hw3Tests$1.run(Hw3Tests.java:29)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Above is very sub-optimal code. It can be easily be rewritten to use a constant (`static final Pattern`) so that the pattern has to be compiled only once. Furthermore, it is very easy to rewrite in such a way that only a single `Matcher` instance is retrieved with a single call to `Pattern.matcher(String)`. The error when calling `group()` without `matches()` or `find()` is not very clear though, it should just throw an `IllegalStateException` instead.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Why using Regex in java is so verbose?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

`pattern.matcher(input)` always creates a new matcher, so you'd need to call `matches()` again.

Try:

```
Matcher m = responseCodePattern.matcher(firstHeader);
m.matches();
m.groupCount();
m.group(0); //must call matches() first
...
```

Answer (score 16):

You are constantly overwriting the matches you got by using

```
System.out.println(responseCodePattern.matcher(firstHeader).matches());
System.out.println(responseCodePattern.matcher(firstHeader).groupCount());
```

Each line creates a new Matcher object.

You should go

```
Matcher matcher = responseCodePattern.matcher(firstHeader);
System.out.println(matcher.matches());
System.out.println(matcher.groupCount());
```

Comment: That's the crux of the problem: matchers have state so the OP is, as you've said, constantly overwriting them. A very easy mistake to miss...and you've explained it very well.

Answer (score 8):

I was experiencing the same, but I'm writing this answer because I noticed something else:

As others stated, **you have to call either**

```
matcher.matches()
```

or

```
matcher.find();
```

**Before you can call**

```
matcher.group(1);
```

**However**, if you are using the **results()** call, you **won't explicitly have to call those methods above** and the results are **immediately available**.

```
pattern
        .matcher(pathname)
        .results()
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .get(0)
        .group(1);
```

I think this is intentionally the case, but I'm just adding it here in addition

> **No need to call matcher.find() or matcher.matches() when using matcher.results()**.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can call `matcher.find();` before `matcher.group(1)`