# Java RegEx no match found error

Tags: java, regex

Following regex giving me `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found` error

```
String requestpattern = "^[A-Za-z]+ \\/+(\\w+)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(requestpattern);
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(requeststring);
return matcher.group(1);
```

where request string is

```
POST //upload/sendData.htm HTTP/1.1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `\w` (word character) is `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. It won't match "`/`", "`.`" or "`/`" (they all appear after "`//`").

Comment: I am expecting it to give upload as output

Comment: possible duplicate of ["No match Found" when using matcher's group method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674268/no-match-found-when-using-matchers-group-method)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No match has been attempted. Call `find()` before calling `group()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String requeststring = "POST //upload/sendData.htm HTTP/1.1";
    String requestpattern = "^[A-Za-z]+ \\/+(\\w+)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(requestpattern);
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(requeststring);
    System.out.println(matcher.find());
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
true
upload
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Matcher#group(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) throws :

```
IllegalStateException - If no match has yet been attempted, or if the 
previous match operation failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expression requires one or more letters, followed by a space, followed by one or more forward slashes, followed by one or more word characters. Your test string doesn't match. The exception is triggered because you're trying to access a group on a matcher that returns no matches.

Your test string matches up to the slash after "upload", because the slash isn't matched by `\w`, which only includes word characters. Word characters are letters, digits, and underscores. See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand

Comment: I am expecting it to give upload as output